# Hyperlinks in JSQMessagesViewController messages

Tags: jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using the JSQMessages framework which is super awesome but I'm trying to enable hyperlinks in both the sent and received text messages - essentially i want to apply a find and replace system where certain words are replaced with pre determined hyperlinks, for example the word "stackoverflow" would turn into a hyperlink to stackoverflow when the user presses the send message button. The message receiver would then receive the hyperlink.

I have the find and replace system working fine however I'm struggling with the hyperlinks. As far as I can tell there doesn't seem to be any way to add hyperlinks to the messages as the "text" message element used to pass execute the message is an NSString and therefore cannot have a url attributed to it. However I hope I'm wrong, are hyperlinks, i.e. a word that links/executes a url when it's tapped, in text messages possible? If so what would be the recommended approach?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

And for Swift 2.0 :

```
let attributes: [String:AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.redColor(), NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: 1]

cell.textView!.linkTextAttributes = attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code in collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath

Activate the data indicator as well..

```
cell.textView.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAll;

    cell.textView.linkTextAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor],
                                                  NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleNone | NSUnderlineStyleNone) };
```